# Find and remove all in mongo/mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is there any way in mongoid to find and 'read' all documents in a collection while also removing them in one, atomic query?

So far I was using:

```
Model.collection.find().to_json
Model.delete_all
```

Which can be easily broken by adding more data to collection between those two instructions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could, for example, **rename** the underlying collection to something like `tmp_cf20c448f824763454ada2c4b2434178`. Then all new writes will go to a new, automatically created collection with old name, and you can, without haste and worries, read all documents and then simply drop that temp collection.

This kind of stuff is usually done more easily using the underlying ruby driver (10gen's `mongo` for mongoid 2.x or `moped` for mongoid 3.x).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :). You should accept answers that solve your problem (little green checkmark to the left). Also you can upvote great answers, this will encourage answerers and indicate usefullness of the post to the community.

Comment: Oh, didn't see the checkmark. I tried to upvote, but I don't have enough points yet :)

Answer (score 16):

There is a simpler solution to this. You can do:

```
Model.collection.drop
```

It will drop the current collection, and create a new one (empty of course) with the same name.